# ¿Como inhabilitar los botones de reserva?

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, params

Esta aplicación creada en el ámbito de Laravel en la que trabajamos, es para hacer reservas en un salón de belleza.

El sistema establecido de reservas es por franjas horarias. Cada ***franja horaria*** tiene un cupo determinado de servicios.
Permite seleccionar un amplio margen de fechas, hasta 5 días.
Los servicios son: corte de cabello, manicura, lavado de cabello, etc., etc.

Por ejemplo:
**-de 10:00 h. - 11:00 h, se permiten 3 servicios diferentes,**
**- de 11:00 h. - 12:00 h se permiten 2 servicios diferentes.**

El problema está en que no consigo inhabilitar los botones de reservas cuando el cupo de servicios está completo en una franja horaria.
Por supuesto, no permite hacer una reserva si el cupo está completo, y te lo notifica con una alerta, pero esto es muy mala experiencia de usuario, ya que si todas las franjas horarias están completas en los próximos 3 días, el usuario debe ir realizando la reserva hora por hora, y recibiendo la alerta de: **"Esta franja horaria está completa"**

Cuando la franja horaria ya paso, los botones correspondientes, se inhabilitan automáticamente.

Necesito hacer lo mismo cuando las franjas horarias estén completas de reservas, se haya completado el cupo de cada franja horaria.

Hice pruebas con la ayuda de un amigo, pero nuestros conocimiento, son algo limitados en este area.
La lógica está en dos archivos en los cuales hicimos algunos cambios, pero los botones no se inhabilitan, y además si pulsamos muestran un error 500.

CAMBIOS EN PRIMER ARCHIVO:

```
// Aquí verificamos si la franja horaria ha alcanzado el límite de servicios
      var disabled = currentTime > fromTime || item.appointments_count >= item.max_client ? 'disabled' : '';
```

CAMBIOS EN EL SEGUNDO ARCHIVO:

```
 // Verifica si ya hay demasiados clientes o si la franja horaria ha pasado
    $already_appointed = ParlourBooking::where('parlour_id', $parlour->id)
        ->where('schedule_id', $validated['schedule_id'])
        ->count();

    $current_time = now();
    $selected_schedule = ParlourListHasSchedule::find($validated['schedule']);
    $selected_schedule_datetime = $selected_schedule->date . ' ' . $selected_schedule->from_time;

    // Si ya hay demasiados clientes o la franja horaria ha pasado, muestra un mensaje de error
    if ($already_appointed >= $schedule->max_client || $current_time > $selected_schedule_datetime) {
        return back()->with(['error' => ['¡Esta franja horaria está completa o ha pasado!']]);
    }
```

EStos son los archivos completos:

PRIMER ARCHIVO:

```
@php
$app_local = get_default_language_code();
@endphp
@extends('frontend.layouts.master')

@push("css")
<style>
  .danger {
    background-color: #cca87643;
    border-radius: 10px;
  }

  .text--disable {
    color: #ffffffcf
  }
</style>
@endpush

@section('content')
<section class="make-appointment pt-120 pb-60">
  <div class="container">
    <form action="{{ setRoute('parlour.booking.store') }}" method="post">
      @csrf
      <input type="hidden" name="parlour" value="{{ $parlour->slug }}">
      <input type="hidden" name="price" id="price">
      <div class="row justify-content-center">
        <div class="col-lg-10">
          <div class="appointment-area">
            <h3 class="title"><i class="fas fa-info-circle text--base mb-20"></i> {{ __("Make Appointment") }}</h3>
            <div class="salon-thumb">
              <img src="{{ get_image(@$parlour->image, 'site-section') }}" alt="img">
            </div>
            <div class="about-details">
              <div class="salon-title">
                <h3 class="title"><i class="las la-user-alt"></i> {{ __("Parlour Details") }}</h3>
              </div>
              <div class="list-wrapper">
                <div class="preview-area">
                  <div class="preview-item">
                    <p>{{ __("Parlour Name") }} :</p>
                  </div>
                  <div class="preview-details">
                    <p>{{ @$parlour->name ?? '' }}</p>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="preview-area">
                  <div class="preview-item">
                    <p>{{ __("Parlour Address") }} :</p>
                  </div>
                  <div class="preview-details">
                    <p>{{ @$parlour->address ?? '' }}</p>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="preview-area">
                  <div class="preview-item">
                    <p>{{ __("Experience") }} :</p>
                  </div>
                  <div class="preview-details">
                    <p>{{ @$parlour->experience ?? '' }}</p>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="salon-title pt-4">
                <h3 class="title"><i class="las la-street-view"></i> {{ __("Service Select") }}</h3>
              </div>
              <div class="service-select">
                <div class="service-option pt-10">
                  @foreach (@$parlour->services as $item)
                  <div class="service-item">
                    <div class="service-inner">
                      <input type="checkbox" name="service[]" value="{{ $item->service_name }}" class="hide-input service" id="service_{{ $item->id }}" data-item="{{ json_encode($item) }}">
                      <label for="service_{{ $item->id }}" class="package--amount">
                        <p>{{ $item->service_name }} <span>{{ get_default_currency_symbol() }}{{ get_amount($item->price) }} </span></p>
                      </label>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  @endforeach
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="shedule-title pt-4">
                <h3 class="title"><i class="fas fa-history"> </i> {{ __("Schedule") }}</h3>
              </div>
              <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-3">
                  <div class="date-picker">
                    <div class="row">
                      <div class="col-xl-12 form-group">
                        @php
                        $currentDate = \Carbon\Carbon::now();
                        $todaysDate = \Carbon\Carbon::now()->format('d F, Y');
                        $schedule_date = $parlour->number_of_dates;
                        @endphp
                        <input type="hidden" class="todays-date" value="{{ $todaysDate }}">
                        <label>{{ __("Select Date") }} <span>*</span></label>
                        <select class="form--control nice-select date" name="date">
                          @for ($i = 0; $i < $schedule_date; $i++) <option value="{{ $currentDate->format('d F, Y') }}">{{ $currentDate->format('d F, Y') }}</option>
                            @php
                            $currentDate->addDay();
                            @endphp
                            @endfor
                        </select>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
                @php
                $current_time = now()->setTimeZone($basic_settings->timezone)->format('H:i');
                @endphp
                <input type="hidden" class="current_time" value="{{ $current_time }}">
                <div class="col-lg-9">
                  <div class="shedule-area">
                    <label>{{ __("Select Time") }} <span>*</span></label>
                    <div class="shedule-option" data-item="{{ json_encode($parlour->schedules) }}">
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="appointment-footer pt-5">
                <div class="col-xl-12 col-lg-12 form-group">
                  @include('admin.components.form.textarea',[
                  'label' => __("Message").'<span class="text--warning">'.'('.__("Optional").')'.'</span>',
                  'name' => 'message',
                  'placeholder' => __("Write Here")."...",
                  'value' => old("message")
                  ])
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-12 form-group pt-3">
                  <button type="submit" class="btn--base small w-100">{{ __("Checkout") }} ( <span class="price">{{ get_default_currency_symbol()  }} </span> )<i class="fas fa-chevron-circle-right ms-1"></i></button>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>
</section>
@endsection
@push("script")
<script>
  $('.service').on('change', function() {
    var servicePrice = [];
    $('.service:checked').each(function() {
      var checkedPrice = $(this).data('item');
      var price = parseFloat(checkedPrice.price)
      servicePrice.push(price);
    });
    var totalPrice = servicePrice.reduce(function(a, b) {
      return a + b;
    }, 0);
    $('.price').text('{{ get_default_currency_symbol() }}' + totalPrice.toFixed(2))
    $('#price').val(totalPrice.toFixed(2));
  });
  $(document).ready(function() {
    var selectedDate = $('.date').val();
    var todaysDate = $('.todays-date').val();
    var currentTime = $('.current_time').val();
    var data = JSON.parse($('.shedule-option').attr("data-item"));
    run(selectedDate, todaysDate, currentTime, data);
  });
  $('.date').on('change', function() {
    var selectedDate = $(this).val();
    var todaysDate = $('.todays-date').val();
    var currentTime = $('.current_time').val();
    var data = JSON.parse($('.shedule-option').attr("data-item"));
    $('.shedule-option').html('');
    run(selectedDate, todaysDate, currentTime, data);
  });

  function run(selectedDate, todaysDate, currentTime, data) {
    $.each(data, function(index, item) {
      var fromTime = item.from_time;
      var disabled = currentTime > fromTime ? 'disabled' : '';
      var disableClassName = disabled === 'disabled' ? 'danger' : '';
      var textClass = disabled === 'disabled' ? 'text--disable' : '';
      var itemData = '';

      if (todaysDate == selectedDate) {
        itemData += `
                    <div class="shedule-item">
                        <div class="shedule-inner ${disableClassName}">
                            <input type="radio" name="schedule" class="hide-input" value="${item.id}" id="shedule_${item.id}" ${disabled}>
                            <label for="shedule_${item.id}" class="package--amount">
                                <strong class="${textClass}">${item.from_time} - </strong> 
                                <strong class="${textClass}">${item.to_time}</strong>
                            </label>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    `;
        $('.shedule-option').append(itemData);
      } else {
        itemData += `
                    <div class="shedule-item">
                        <div class="shedule-inner">
                            <input type="radio" name="schedule" class="hide-input" value="${item.id}" id="shedule_${item.id}">
                            <label for="shedule_${item.id}" class="package--amount">
                                <strong>${item.from_time} - </strong> 
                                <strong>${item.to_time}</strong>
                            </label>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    `;
        $('.shedule-option').append(itemData);
      }
    });
  }
</script>
@endpush
```

SEGUNDO ARCHIVO:

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers\Frontend;

use Exception;
use Illuminate\Support\Str;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Models\TemporaryData;
use App\Models\ParlourBooking;
use App\Models\UserNotification;
use App\Models\Admin\ParlourList;
use App\Models\Admin\UsefullLink;
use App\Models\Admin\SiteSections;
use App\Constants\SiteSectionConst;
use App\Models\Admin\BasicSettings;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use App\Constants\PaymentGatewayConst;
use App\Models\Admin\TransactionSetting;
use App\Notifications\emailNotification;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator;
use App\Models\Admin\ParlourListHasSchedule;
use App\Models\Admin\PaymentGatewayCurrency;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Notification;
use KingFlamez\Rave\Facades\Rave as Flutterwave;
use App\Http\Helpers\PaymentGateway as PaymentGatewayHelper;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Session;

class ParlourBookingController extends Controller
{
  /**
   * Method for show parlour booking page
   * @param $slug
   * @param \Illuminate\Http\Request $request
   */
  public function getService(Request $request, $slug)
  {
    $page_title         = "| Parlour Booking";
    $parlour            = ParlourList::with(['schedules', 'services'])->where('slug', $slug)->first();
    $validated_user     = auth()->user();
    $footer_slug        = Str::slug(SiteSectionConst::FOOTER_SECTION);
    $footer             = SiteSections::getData($footer_slug)->first();
    $usefull_links      = UsefullLink::where('status', true)->get();
    $contact_slug       = Str::slug(SiteSectionConst::CONTACT_SECTION);
    $contact            = SiteSections::getData($contact_slug)->first();


    return view('frontend.pages.parlour-booking.index', compact(
      'page_title',
      'parlour',
      'validated_user',
      'footer',
      'usefull_links',
      'contact'
    ));
  }
  /**
   * Method for store appointment booking information and passed it to preview page
   * @param \Illuminate\Http\Request $request
   */
  public function store(Request $request)
  {
    if (auth()->check() == false) return back()->with(['error' => ['Please Login First.']]);
    $charge_data            = TransactionSetting::where('slug', 'parlour')->where('status', 1)->first();
    $validator              = Validator::make($request->all(), [
      'parlour'           => 'required',
      'price'             => 'required',
      'service'           => "required|array",
      'service.*'         => "required|string|max:255",
      'date'              => "required",
      'schedule'          => 'required',
      'message'           => "nullable"
    ]);
    if ($validator->fails()) {
      return back()->withErrors($validator)->withInput($request->all());
    }
    $validated                  = $validator->validate();
    $validated['slug']          = Str::uuid();
    $slug                       = $validated['parlour'];
    $parlour                    = ParlourList::where('slug', $slug)->first();
    if (!$parlour) return back()->with(['error' => ['Parlour Not Found!']]);

    $validated['user_id']       = auth()->user()->id;


    $validated['parlour_id']   = $parlour->id;

    $schedule = ParlourListHasSchedule::where('id', $validated['schedule'])->whereHas('parlour', function ($q) use ($parlour) {
      $q->where('id', $parlour->id);
    })->first();

    if (!$schedule) {
      return back()->with(['error' => ['Schedule Not Found!']]);
    }
    $validated['schedule_id']   = $validated['schedule'];

    $price                      = floatval($validated['price']);
    $fixed_charge               = floatval($charge_data->fixed_charge);
    $percent_charge             = floatval($charge_data->percent_charge);
    $total_percent_charge       = ($percent_charge / 100) * $price;
    $total_charge               = $fixed_charge + $total_percent_charge;
    $total_price                = $price + $total_charge;
    $validated['total_charge']  = $total_charge;
    $validated['price']         = $price;
    $validated['payable_price'] = $total_price;
    $validated['status']        = global_const()::PARLOUR_BOOKING_STATUS_REVIEW_PAYMENT;

    $alrady_appointed = ParlourBooking::where('parlour_id', $parlour->id)
    ->where('schedule_id', $validated['schedule_id'])
    ->count();

    if ($alrady_appointed >= $schedule->max_client) {
      return back()->with(['error' => ['¡Esta hora esta completa!']]);
    }

    $next_appointment_no = $alrady_appointed + 1;
    $validated['serial_number'] = $next_appointment_no;

    try {
      $booking = ParlourBooking::create($validated);
    } catch (Exception $e) {
      return back()->with(['error' => ['Something went wrong! Please try again.']]);
    }
    return redirect()->route('parlour.booking.preview', $booking->slug);
  }
  /**
   * Method for show the preview page 
   * @param $slug
   * @param \Illuminate\Http\Request $request
   */
  public function preview(Request $request, $slug)
  {
    $page_title         = "| Appointment Preview";
    $booking            = ParlourBooking::with(['parlour', 'schedule', 'payment_gateway'])->where('slug', $slug)->first();
    if (!$booking) {
      return redirect()->route('find.parlour')->with(['error' => ['Booking not found']]);
    }
    $payment_gateway   = PaymentGatewayCurrency::whereHas('gateway', function ($gateway) {
      $gateway->where('slug', PaymentGatewayConst::payment_method_slug());
      $gateway->where('status', 1);
    })->get();
    $footer_slug        = Str::slug(SiteSectionConst::FOOTER_SECTION);
    $footer             = SiteSections::getData($footer_slug)->first();
    $usefull_links      = UsefullLink::where('status', true)->get();
    $contact_slug       = Str::slug(SiteSectionConst::CONTACT_SECTION);
    $contact            = SiteSections::getData($contact_slug)->first();

    return view('frontend.pages.parlour-booking.preview', compact(
      'page_title',
      'booking',
      'payment_gateway',
      'footer',
      'usefull_links',
      'contact'
    ));
  }
  public function deleteBooking(Request $request)
  {
    $booking = ParlourBooking::where('slug', $request->bookingSlug)->first();

    if ($booking) {
      $booking->delete();
      Session::flash('message', ['success'   => ['Booking Time Out!']]);
      return response()->json(['success' => true]);
    }

    return response()->json(['success' => false]);
  }

  /**
   * Method for confirm the booking
   * @param $slug
   * @param \Illuminate\Http\Request $request
   */
  public function confirm(Request $request, $slug)
  {
    $data       = ParlourBooking::with(['payment_gateway', 'parlour', 'schedule', 'user'])->where('slug', $slug)->first();
    $otp_exp_sec = $data->booking_exp_seconds ?? global_const()::BOOKING_EXP_SEC;

    if ($data->created_at->addSeconds($otp_exp_sec) < now()) {
      $data->delete();
      return redirect()->route('find.parlour')->with(['error' => ['Booking Time Out!']]);
    }

    $validator  = Validator::make($request->all(), [
      'payment_method'    => 'required',
    ]);
    $validated  = $validator->validate();
    $from_time  = $data->schedule->from_time ?? '';

    $to_time    = $data->schedule->to_time ?? '';
    $user       = auth()->user();
    $basic_setting = BasicSettings::first();
    if ($validated['payment_method'] == global_const()::CASH_PAYMENT) {
      try {
        $trx_id = generateTrxString('parlour_bookings', 'trx_id', 'PB', 8);
        $data->update([
          'trx_id'            => $trx_id,
          'payment_method'    => $validated['payment_method'],
          'remark'            => 'CASH',
          'status'            => global_const()::PARLOUR_BOOKING_STATUS_PENDING,
        ]);
        UserNotification::create([
          'user_id'  => auth()->user()->id,
          'message'  => [
            'title' => "Your Booking",
            'parlour'   => $data->parlour->name,
            'date'      => $data->date,
            'from_time' => $from_time,
            'to_time'   => $to_time,
            'serial_number' => $data->serial_number,
            'success'       => "Successfully Booked."
          ],
        ]);
        if ($basic_setting->email_notification == true) {
          Notification::route("mail", $user->email)->notify(new emailNotification($user, $data, $trx_id));
        }
      } catch (Exception $e) {
        return back()->with(['error' => ['Something went wrong! Please try again.']]);
      }
      return redirect()->route('user.my.booking.index')->with(['success' => ['¡Felicidades! Reserva confirmada con éxito.']]);
    } else {
      $requested_data         = [
        'data'              => $data,
        'payment_method'    => $validated['payment_method']
      ];

      try {
        $instance = PaymentGatewayHelper::init($requested_data)->gateway()->render();
      } catch (Exception $e) {
        return back()->with(['error' => [$e->getMessage()]]);
      }
      return $instance;
    }
  }
  /**
   * Method for paypal payment succes
   */
  public function success(Request $request, $gateway)
  {
    $requestData = $request->all();
    $token = $requestData['token'] ?? "";
    $checkTempData = TemporaryData::where("type", $gateway)->where("identifier", $token)->first();
    if (!$checkTempData) return redirect()->route('find.parlour')->with(['error' => ['Transaction faild. Record didn\'t saved properly. Please try again.']]);
    $checkTempData = $checkTempData->toArray();
    try {

      PaymentGatewayHelper::init($checkTempData)->responseReceive();
    } catch (Exception $e) {
      return back()->with(['error' => [$e->getMessage()]]);
    }

    return redirect()->route("user.my.booking.index")->with(['success' => ['¡Felicidades! Reserva confirmada con éxito.']]);
  }
  /**
   * This method for cancel alert of PayPal
   * @method POST
   * @param Illuminate\Http\Request $request
   * @return Illuminate\Http\Request
   */
  public function cancel(Request $request, $gateway)
  {
    $requestData = $request->all();
    $token = $requestData['token'] ?? "";
    if ($token) {
      TemporaryData::where("identifier", $token)->delete();
    }
    return redirect()->route('find.parlour');
  }
  /**
   * Method for stripe payment success
   */
  public function stripePaymentSuccess($trx)
  {

    $token = $trx;
    $checkTempData = TemporaryData::where("type", PaymentGatewayConst::STRIPE)->where("identifier", $token)->first();
    if (!$checkTempData) return redirect()->route('find.parlour')->with(['error' => ['Transaction Failed. Record didn\'t saved properly. Please try again.']]);
    $checkTempData = $checkTempData->toArray();

    try {
      PaymentGatewayHelper::init($checkTempData)->responseReceive();
    } catch (Exception $e) {

      return back()->with(['error' => ["Something Is Wrong..."]]);
    }
    return redirect()->route("user.my.booking.index")->with(['success' => ['¡Felicidades! Reserva confirmada con éxito.']]);
  }

  //flutterwave callback
  public function flutterwaveCallback()
  {

    $status = request()->status;
    //if payment is successful
    if ($status ==  'successful') {

      $transactionID = Flutterwave::getTransactionIDFromCallback();
      $data = Flutterwave::verifyTransaction($transactionID);

      $requestData = request()->tx_ref;
      $token = $requestData;

      $checkTempData = TemporaryData::where("type", 'flutterwave')->where("identifier", $token)->first();

      if (!$checkTempData) return redirect()->route('find.parlour')->with(['error' => ['Transaction faild. Record didn\'t saved properly. Please try again.']]);

      $checkTempData = $checkTempData->toArray();

      try {

        PaymentGatewayHelper::init($checkTempData)->responseReceive();
      } catch (Exception $e) {
        return back()->with(['error' => [$e->getMessage()]]);
      }
      return redirect()->route("user.my.booking.index")->with(['success' => ['¡Felicidades! Reserva confirmada con éxito.']]);
    } elseif ($status ==  'cancelled') {
      return redirect()->route('find.parlour')->with(['error' => ['Parlour Booking Canceled.']]);
    } else {
      return redirect()->route('find.parlour')->with(['error' => ['Transaction failed']]);
    }
  }
  /**
   * SSL Commerz Payment Success
   */
  public function sllCommerzSuccess(Request $request)
  {

    $data           = $request->all();
    $token          = $data['tran_id'];
    $checkTempData  = TemporaryData::where("type", PaymentGatewayConst::SSLCOMMERZ)->where("identifier", $token)->first();

    if (!$checkTempData) return redirect()->route('find.parlour')->with(['error' => ['Transaction Failed. Record didn\'t saved properly. Please try again.']]);
    $checkTempData  = $checkTempData->toArray();
    $creator_id     = $checkTempData['data']->creator_id ?? null;
    $creator_guard  = $checkTempData['data']->creator_guard ?? null;

    $user = Auth::guard($creator_guard)->loginUsingId($creator_id);
    if ($data['status'] != "VALID") {
      return redirect()->route("find.parlour")->with(['error' => ['Failed!']]);
    }
    try {
      PaymentGatewayHelper::init($checkTempData)->responseReceive();
    } catch (Exception $e) {

      return back()->with(['error' => ["Something Is Wrong..."]]);
    }
    return redirect()->route("user.my.booking.index")->with(['success' => ['¡Felicidades! Reserva confirmada con éxito.']]);
  }
  /**
   * razor pay payment gateway callback
   */
  public function razorCallback()
  {
    $request_data = request()->all();
    //if payment is successful
    if ($request_data['razorpay_payment_link_status'] ==  'paid') {
      $token = $request_data['razorpay_payment_link_reference_id'];

      $checkTempData = TemporaryData::where("type", PaymentGatewayConst::RAZORPAY)->where("identifier", $token)->first();
      if (!$checkTempData) return redirect()->route('find.parlour')->with(['error' => ['Transaction Failed. Record didn\'t saved properly. Please try again.']]);
      $checkTempData = $checkTempData->toArray();
      try {
        PaymentGatewayHelper::init($checkTempData)->responseReceive();
      } catch (Exception $e) {
        return back()->with(['error' => [$e->getMessage()]]);
      }
      return redirect()->route("user.my.booking.index")->with(['success' => ['¡Felicidades! Reserva confirmada con éxito.']]);
    } else {
      return redirect()->route('find.parlour')->with(['error' => ['Failed']]);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: esto me parece como que estas haciendo un software para empresas de salon de bellesa?

Comment: te recomendaria buscar un freelance experto en laravel. por que la verdad lo que muestras no es un error, es un requerimiento y en el sitio no hacemos requerimientos de trabajas.